# Resize div with inline svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to resize an SVG to fit the max browser dimensions. The SVG is stored as a DIV's innerHTML. No matter what I do though, the svg will not resize.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/31a9myjg/

```
<div id="root" style="width:10%; height:10%"></div>
```

doesn't do anything

```
<object id="root" width=100 height=100></object>
```

doesn't do anything either. Why is that? Is it possible to resize an svg this way or do I have to turn it into a png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following CSS, which will cause the actual SVG element's width to adaptively resize as required:

```
#root svg {
  width:100%;
}
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle to demonstrate this working](https://jsfiddle.net/cqL6g7th/1/) with your code.

Alternatively, if you want to achieve the same behaviour via javascript, you could update your script with the following (which would make the CSS above redundant):

```
const obj = document.createElement('div');

// svg contains vector data from jsFiddle link in OP
obj.innerHTML = svg;
app.appendChild(obj);

// Adding this achieves the same result as the CSS above    
obj.querySelector('svg').style.width = '100%';
```

#### Update

It is necessary to have a `viewbox` defined on your SVG, for the resizing behaviour shown above to work. The `viewbox` basically represents the domain/dimensions that coordinates in your SVG are relative to.

If a `width` and `height` are defined on your SVG, then the following method for defining a `viewbox` will works well for most situations:

```
const svgElement = obj.querySelector('svg');

const width = svgElement.getAttribute('width');
const height = svgElement.getAttribute('height');

// Set the viewbox "domain" from top left (0,0), to bottom right (width, height)
svgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
```

A working example of this [can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/yum2nhpd/)

Comment: Can you look at the updated fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/31a9myjg/2/

Why does this svg not resize to fit the window?

Comment: @nodel sure - this is because a the svg has no view box defined - please see updated answer. Hope this helps!